# Group object in the category of formal schemes vs. formal group law

Tags: algebraic-geometry, formal-groups

I've been trying to see how both definitions of a formal group coincide:

Take a ring $ R $, a group object in the category of formal schemes over $ R $ is then given by two morphims $ e : R \rightarrow X $, $ \mu : X \times X \rightarrow X $.

For $ X = \widehat{\mathbb{A}}^1_R $, this amounts to two morphisms of $R$-adic algebras $ e : R[[x]] \rightarrow R $ and $ \mu : R[[x]] \rightarrow R[[x,y]] $, but it is easy to see that $ \mathrm{Hom}_R(R[[x]], R) \simeq \mathrm{Nil}(R) $, so there might be more than $1$ possible choice for $ e $. Yet, in the definition of a formal group law, unitality is then stated as $ \mu(x) = x + y + \text{higher terms} $, but if for example $ R = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} $, take $ e : X \mapsto 2 $, then unitality reduces to $ \mu(x)(2, Y) = Y, \mu(x)(X, 2) = X $, but then $ \mu(x) = x + y -2 $ satisfies unitality and associativity.

In the case of $ R $ a field, there is of course no longer any problem, but I've seen the formal group law definition stated for $ R $ in this way.

So is it that we require formal group laws to actually have a fixed unit morphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the context of formal group laws, one defines adic algebras over $R$ to be augmented $R$-algebra $\eta:A \to R.$ The topology on $A$ is the adic topology generated by $\text{Ker}(\eta),$ which is sometimes also assumed to be complete and separated. The maps between such adic algebras are required to be compatible with this data of the augmentation which fixes the problem you mentioned.

Comment: Requiring that the morphisms respect the augmentations does seem to solve this problem. So does this mean that formal group laws don't exactly correspond to the formal groups on the completed affine line?

Comment: That seems to be the case to me when you are working over a base as in your example.

Comment: This also seems reasonable because the functor parametrizing 1 dimensional commutative formal group laws is corepresentable by the Lazard ring, so in some sense it wants to capture purely equational aspects which wouldn't take the topology/nilpotents of the base ring $R$ into account.

Comment: Looks like this answers my question. I wasn't able to find a source that sheds some light on the correspondance between the two concepts, except for [the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/formal+group#FormalGroupLaw) which seems to take the wrong definition as you outlined.

Comment: Actually, I think if by "continuous" they mean that its a map of rings which preserves the graded pieces of the adic filtration then it seems to be okay. From the link you provided it seems like that is the sense they had in mind. But that doesn't seem to be the usual definition of continuous.